# how to run command line using flask framework from website

Tags: python, flask

everyone.

I have a doubt, how to run a command line using flask framework, my code like this:

```
import click
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.cli.command()
def initdb(name):
    """init database"""
    click.echo('here inti mydb', name)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/runbutton', methods=['POST'])

def runbutton():
    nombre = request.form['nombre']
    response = initdb(nombre)
    return 'ok'

if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

the appweb show me an error 'the connection was reset', and let me know if this is possible and what can I do, please.

[image]

regards
Angel

Answer (score -1):

How are you running it on the command line? If you set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to your script and call `flask run` on the command line, it should start the Flask server. [This is shown on the quickstart documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#quickstart). Additionally, you shouldn't need the lines

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if you run the server in this manner.

Comment: Hi, well I need when I clicked in my website that click run a command line in the console. when I run flask is working fine, but when I clicked in the button the web server was reseted. just I need a tip how to run command line from website.